# C## -- with two pound signs?

Tags: naming

- **Visual Basic .NET**
- **C##**
- **etc**

C#?  With two pound signs?

It's on so many of these programming résumés we're getting -- from random people -- listed as a qualification.

Any ideas what these folks are talking about?  Is this convention an accidental holdover from C++, or something?

**EDIT/ANSWER:** Turns out the corporate résumé management system converts the "C#" that applicants specify to "C##".  That is just fantastic.

Comment: Some how I think it meant to be C#

Comment: C Sharpy Sharp.NET, all new language... surely these are just typo's? People who cant be bothered proof reading?

Comment: C# == D flat, therefore C## = D. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)

Comment: Makes it easy to tell who *not* to hire.

Comment: @Challkey: Point taken.  Also, proofreading is one word.  ;)!

Comment: C++ has two, C# has four, C## has eight. Eight, man! That's hardcore.

Comment: This is an opportunity to "clear your desk" of useless resumes while rejoicing that "C# Turbo Plus Advanced" doesn't actually mean something !

Comment: c++++++++ sounds pretty awesome to me

Comment: Depends... do they have 5 years of C##, or 25?

Comment: Have you checked the job poster... maybe you're accidentally hiring C## developers **D:**

Comment: And let me guess... he has five years of experience on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C Sharp - now even sharper!

Answer (score 7):

My guess is you shouldn't hire them.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a recruiter who doesn't know what he is talking about is trying to impress you.

Answer (score 2):

That résumé speaks for itself - little attention to detail. Not good for a programmer...

Answer (score 1):

If it's on "so many" I'm willing to bet that the candidates don't know what they are talking about. Similarly, I have seen 'C+' listed as a language as well.

It's not uncommon for people to list as many languages on their resume as they can, because the Bad Ones think that even knowing the name of the language gives them a foot ahead of someone who doesn't. This is obviously a flaw in logic.

I can't remember exactly where I heard this story before (someone's blog, maybe someone will remember) but the exact situation is described. A candidate comes in with a resume listing all of these languages. As the interviewer asks the candidate to demonstrate their knowledge of the language by writing some code, the candidate freezes. When the interviewer asks why, the candidate responds with "I didn't say I knew how to write in those languages, just that I know of them!"

Answer (score 1):

I received a resume before has this line in the list of experiences

C \ C+ \ C++ \ C#

:)

Comment: He's missing 'C+++' Because "#" is just 4 little tiny pluses all together, right?